# How to build a x64, Windows 7 compatible application?

Tags: .net, 64-bit, registry-virtualization

We have an legacy application that accesses the registry.  Because it is a 32bit application it accesses the registry in Windows 7 through Registry Virtualization when referencing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software.  **My question is what setting(s) in Visual Studio do we need to modify to compile our applications where they access the registry "normally" without going through Registry Virtualization?**

Comment: This is a non-answer, but I have to suggest *not using the registry* if you can avoid it.  This is .NET, so use a config file.

Comment: @Steven we have and still are considering using a config file.  I just want to make sure before I build a case to change that code I have a solid understanding of how to accomplish this.

Comment: Fair enough.  I hope you succeed in building a case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to compile the legacy application to target x64.  An application that is explicitly targeting x64 will not be subject to registry virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the Registry Virtualization page closely, you will notice that the virtualization is not limited to 64-bit Windows. It only states that only 32-bit processes will be virtualized. But the virtualization is done on both 32- and 64-bit Vista and later. So the question title and the x64 tag are a bit misleading.

To answer your question, the same page says this:
"Registry virtualization is disabled for the following: ... Processes that have requestedExecutionLevel specified in their manifests."

So you can disable the virtualization by adding a manifest file to your executable that specifies its execution level. There is at least a Microsoft KB article for how to do it in Visual Studio 2005: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944276.

Comment: Yes, that would also work for the Registry Virtualization problem.

However, the embedded manifest has other advantages too. It shows that the application is "Vista/Win 7 aware", and it specifies whether the application needs to run with administrator or standard user privileges. I would definitely recommend adding it in any case.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that since the registry virtualization happens on both 32- and 64-bit OS, the only legitimate solution I know on 32-bit Windows is to create the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\...");
return (string)key.GetValue("blah");
```

and add access to the registry in the customtrust.config file.

or doesn't that work in Windows 7?

Comment: That code works, but not for this old application.  I read documentation and it states that if the application isn't compatible with Windows 7 then its registry access is routed to a different location using Registry Virtualization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know that existed. Could you impersonate a user that has access to the registry key? That would remove the use of Registry Virtualization.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that the application configures a global registry location that multiple applications access.  The applications can't find the settings because they are being stashed away in this virtual location.